# Perforce command line: How to use -i flag in "p4 client -i"?

Tags: c#, command-line, client, perforce, workspace

I'd like to edit/create a workspace on the command line without any text editor popping up.  The docs say to use the -i flag to use Standard Input.  What is the syntax / format of this usage?

Passing a file works correctly:
p4 client -i < fileDefiningTheWorkspace.txt

Passing the actual string defining the workspace doesn't work:
p4 client -i "Root: C:\The\Root\r\nOptions: noallwrite noclobber....."

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Glad you asked this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just entering a string like that won't pass it in standard-input. You need to direct some input, as with your first example of passing a file.

If you really need the string as part of a command line, you would need to use something like echo to pipe the appropriate text in. However echo doesn't support newlines, so you need to echo each line separately:

(echo line1 & echo line2 & echo line3) | p4 client -i

It'll get pretty ugly pretty quickly.

As you seem to be really wanting to know how to do this from c#, here's a very rough and ready example of firing up a command-line process and feeding it input:

```
        ProcessStartInfo s_info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"sort.exe");
        s_info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        s_info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        s_info.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = s_info;
        proc.Start();
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("123");
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("abc");
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("456");
        proc.StandardInput.Close();
        String output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        System.Console.Write(output);
```

Comment: You could use a here document. Bash also has `<<<"your message here"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My end goal is to do this in c#, by creating the workspace details in a string, and passing it to a procedure to run.  I could write the file to disk temporarily, then use that file as above (p4 client -i < theFile.txt) but that seems like the wrong way to go.

Comment: From C#, why not just use the API?

Comment: Can't use the API, sadly.  Has to be command line in a process.

Comment: Well if you invoke the command line from c#, you should be able to pipe the definition straight into the input stream.

Comment: Ok, maybe that's my real question then - simply how to pipe it into the input stream.  (c# noob).

Comment: Though I'm not from C# world, the tip on doing multiple `echo`s (each per line) helped really well. You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

After i've dealt with that issue in my case the solution seem like this:

```
P4Process.StartInfo.Arguments="client -i"
StreamWriter myStreamWriter = P4Process.StandardInput;
                String inputText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Program Files\Perforce\clientSpec.txt");
                myStreamWriter.Write(inputText);
                P4Process.StandardInput.Close();                  

                P4Process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                P4Process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                P4Process.WaitForExit();
```

for me it was the same as:

```
p4 client - i < clientSpec.txt
```